# Insert constraint foreign key in spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mariadb

I have table with two columns as below

```
 Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| hakemus_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fk_duuni_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fk_ehdokas_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |               |
```

And i have insert method in Dao class like this

```
public void insertHakemus(Hakemus hakemus) {
        String sql="insert into hakemus(fk_duuni_id, fk_ehdokas_id) values(?,?)";
        int ehdokas_id= hakemus.getEhdokas_id();
        int duuni_id = hakemus.getDuuni_id();
        Object[] ob = new Object[]{duuni_id,ehdokas_id};
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, ob);

    }
```

In controller i get parameters from view by using annotation @RequestParam to get duuni_id and ehdokas_id from View

```
@RequestMapping(value="sendCV.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String receiveCV(@RequestParam(value="duuni_id") Integer duuni_id,@RequestParam(value="ehdokas_id") Integer ehdokas_id, @ModelAttribute(value="ehdokas") EhdokasImpl ehdokas, Model model){
        Hakemus hakemus = new HakemusImpl();
        hakemus.setEhdokas_id(ehdokas_id);
        hakemus.setDuuni_id(duuni_id);
        System.out.println(duuni_id);
        System.out.println(ehdokas_id);
        if(!ehdokas_id.equals(0) && !duuni_id.equals(0)){
            ehdokasdao.editEhdokas(ehdokas);
            hakemusdao.insertHakemus(hakemus);
            return "redirect:tyopaikat.do";
        }
```

I use two system printer to check duuni_id and ehdokas_id is null or not and the result i got it's ok. It means parameter's value pass successful from View to Controller. But when i run this code, i got error java.lang.NullPointerException in insertHakemus() method, do anyone have any ideas?!

Stacktrace

```
Apr 13, 2016 7:10:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/vjb.de] is completed
6
1
Apr 13, 2016 7:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [vietjob] in context with path [/vjb.de] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at vjb.de.vietjob.dao.hakemusDAO.HakemusDaoImpl.insertHakemus(HakemusDaoImpl.java:29)
    at vjb.de.vietjob.controller.HakemusController.receiveCV(HakemusController.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Bean class

```
package vjb.de.vietjob.bean.hakemus;

public class HakemusImpl implements Hakemus {
      private int hakemus_id;
      private int duuni_id;
      private int ehdokas_id;
    public int getHakemus_id() {
        return hakemus_id;
    }
    public void setHakemus_id(int hakemus_id) {
        this.hakemus_id = hakemus_id;
    }
    public int getDuuni_id() {
        return duuni_id;
    }
    public void setDuuni_id(int duuni_id) {
        this.duuni_id = duuni_id;
    }
    public int getEhdokas_id() {
        return ehdokas_id;
    }
    public void setEhdokas_id(int ehdokas_id) {
        this.ehdokas_id = ehdokas_id;
    }


}
```

Comment: It's not null bro

{Apr 13, 2016 7:21:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/vjb.de] is completed
6
1
vjb.de.vietjob.dao.ehdokasDAO.EhdokasDaoImpl@365d1de8}

Comment: Hakemus hakemus = new HakemusImpl(); Should not this be as Hakemus hakemus = new Hakemus();

Comment: Sorry for that comment i should have looked at your logs closely. Dao cannot be null

Comment: HakemusImpl is class implements from interface class Hakemus, cannot do as you said.

Comment: which is line (HakemusDaoImpl.java:29) in your code?

Comment: From the code you posted the reference that most likely to be null is jdbcTemplate. May you please indicate how you are configuring and injecting the jdbcTemplate

Comment: may be your jdbc template is null?

Comment: With other object i also do the same and no problem happen. But when i do the object with two attribute which are primary key, i got this problem.

Comment: It's is this line:

jdbcTemplate.update(sql, ob);

Comment: Wow, you are right! beautiful :)). I forgot add @Inject annotation for JdbcTemplate, so noob :(.

Comment: Perfect. glad its working

Comment: How can i say thanks to you?

Comment: Will post an answer and please accept it and upvote it. thanks

Comment: Where the button i can upvote for you? because i don't see it from your answer, sr i'm a new comer in stackoverflow.

Comment: refresh this page you would see my answer at the bottom. You can see two  arrows , up and down kind of . Click on the upvote

Comment: Maybe it's done! Thanks again!

Comment: Can see now thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please check your jdbctemplate it might be null.